# WebSphere Liberty 18.0.0.1 post parameters limit

Tags: post, configuration, websphere-liberty, open-liberty

In our Web Application that run on **WebSphere Liberty 18.0.0.1** we got this error:

> exceeding maximum parameters allowed per request 10 000 current 10 000 cannot add more

Before, that application was deployed on **WAS (traditional) 8.5.5.x** and we had this custom property: `"com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.maxParamPerRequest": "-1"`.

But I can't found any configuration on *Liberty*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this post [Enabling UNLIMITED parameter requests](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21962614).
For Liberty you can set it in `server.xml` like this:

```
<webContainer maxParamPerRequest="-1"/>
```

Check if it will solve your issue.

Comment: Nope: it's not valid for Liberty 18.0.0.1

Comment: The property looks valid to me - do you see some kind of error when you set it?  Or do you just continue to see the exceeding maximum parameters message?

Comment: I didn't tried in production because the server.xml validator in RAD told me that that property wasn't right and deleted it. Also it's not mentioned in IBM Knowledge Center and it's not managed by server config designer in Liberty Admin Center. This morning I tried and it worked. Damn IBM. Thanks to you both.

Comment: @Paso82 Thanks for checking that out. We will try to make documentation updated.